# Trying to ROLL-UP multiple rows into a SINGLE row using the MAX column solution but not working

Tags: t-sql

Here is my SQL Server result set:

[image]

I am trying to get the Company Vehicle 2 info up in the FIRST ROW.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Here is the SQL code that I attempted by using the MAX solution that I found in StackOverflow:

```
SELECT tpcbpv1.PolicySysID, tpcbpv1.[Policy Number] 
    ,CASE 
        WHEN RN = 1 THEN MAX(tpcbpv1.PolicyVehicleSysID)
    END as [Company Vehicle Number 1]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN RN = 1 THEN MAX(tpcbpv1.vYear)
    END as [Vehicle Year 1]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN RN = 2 THEN MAX(tpcbpv1.PolicyVehicleSysID)
    END as [Company Vehicle Number 2]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN RN = 2 THEN MAX(tpcbpv1.vYear)
    END as [Vehicle Year 2]

FROM #tempPolicyCoverageByPolicyVehicle tpcbpv1
WHERE PolicySysID = 179478
GROUP BY tpcbpv1.PolicySysID, tpcbpv1.[Policy Number], RN
ORDER BY PolicySysID asc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `RN` from the `GROUP BY` and nest the case statements in a `max()`

```
SELECT tpcbpv1.PolicySysID
     , tpcbpv1.[Policy Number] 
     , max(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN tpcbpv1.PolicyVehicleSysID END ) as [Company Vehicle Number 1] 
     , max(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN tpcbpv1.vYear END)               as [Vehicle Year 1]
     , max(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN tpcbpv1.PolicyVehicleSysID END ) as [Company Vehicle Number 2]
     , max(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN tpcbpv1.vYear END)               as [Vehicle Year 2]
FROM #tempPolicyCoverageByPolicyVehicle tpcbpv1
WHERE PolicySysID = 179478
GROUP BY tpcbpv1.PolicySysID, tpcbpv1.[Policy Number]
ORDER BY PolicySysID asc
```

Comment: @Melinda Always happy to help